# C# Merging 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I'm developing an app in C# targeting .NET 3.5.  In it, I have 2 similar dictionaries that contain validation criteria for a specific set of elements in my app.  Both dictionaries have identical signatures.  The first dictionary has the default settings and the 2nd dictionary contains some user defined settings.

```
var default_settings = new Dictionary<string, MyElementSettings>();
var custom_settings = new Dictionary<string, MyElementSettings>();
```

I would like to combine the 2 dictionaries into one that contains the elements of both dictionaries.

The problem that I am running into is it is possible for both dictionaries to have the some of the same key values.  The basic rule I want is to have a combination of both dictionary and if there are any keys in the custom_settings that already exist in the default_settings, the custom_settings value will overwrite the default_settings value.  The best solution i have is just a foreach loop, check if the key exists in the other dictionary, and if not, add it.

```
foreach (var item in custom_settings)
{
    if (default_settings.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        default_settings[item.Key] = item.Value;
    else
        default_settings.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

I've done some basic LINQ queries, but I'm still working on learning the more advanced stuff.  I've seen a few queries that will merge 2 dictionaries, but most involve grouping any element with duplicate keys, or only return a collection with just the duplicate keys/  Is there a LINQ query or expression that will mimic the behavior of the foreach loop I am using?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Two points:

1. LINQ isn't great for executing side effects. In this case, you're attempting to mutate an existing collection rather than execute a query, so I would shy away from a pure LINQ solution.
2. The [setter on the generic dictionary's indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) already has the effect of adding the key-value pair if the key doesn't exist, or overwriting the value if it does.

> When you set the property value, if
>   the key is in the Dictionary, the value associated with
>   that key is replaced by the assigned
>   value. If the key is not in the
>   Dictionary, the key and
>   value are added to the dictionary.

So your `foreach` loop is essentially equivalent to:

```
foreach (var item in custom_settings)
{
   default_settings[item.Key] = item.Value;
}
```

Now that's pretty terse already, so I don't think LINQ is going to help you all that much.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something i did not know.  I'm relatively self taught with C# and never knew you could do that with dictionaries.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Cheers. I'm pretty sure I used the same pattern as your code before I discovered it was redundant (by chance, was poking around with reflector).

Comment: You also can use the `TryGetValue` method to check if the object is already present in the dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a nice extension method based on Ani's answer.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Merge<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> me, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> merge)
    {
        foreach (var item in merge)
        {
            me[item.Key] = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change Dictionary on IDictionary

Comment: If this is a dictionary collection `IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValu>> `how can match them?

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to do this a lot, then I'd recommend writing an equality comparer for dictionary keys:

```
private class KeyEqualityComparer<T, U> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<T, U>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<T, U> x, KeyValuePair<T, U> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key);
    }
     
    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<T, U> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then whenever you need to merge dictionaries, you can do the following

```
var comparer = new KeyEqualityComparer<string, MyElementSettings>();
dict1 = dict1.Union(dict2,comparer).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Value);
```

Comment: this one worked for me, even without the `KeyEqualityComparer` class/parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer I selected originally is still the best answer for this particular case, I found myself in another similar situation a little while ago where I had 2 `IEnumerable<>` objects that I wanted to convert to a dictionary and merge together in a similar fashion so I thought I would add that solution here to help someone in the future.  Rather than converting both to a dictionary and using the method in the selected answer, I found a new approach.

I actually posted the [initial solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11121/merging-ienumerable-and-removing-duplicates) on SE-CodeReview and actually had a suggestion to refine it further.  Here's the final code I used:

```
public Dictionary<String, Foo> Merge(XElement element1, XElement element2)
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> firstFoos = GetXmlData(element1); // parse 1st set from XML
    IEnumerable<Foo> secondFoos = GetXmlData(element2); // parse 2nd set from XML

    var result = firstFoos.Union(secondFoos).ToDictionary(k=>k.Name, v=>v);

    return result;
}

public class Foo
{
    public String Name { get; }

    // other Properties and Methods
    // .
    // .
    // .

    public override Boolean Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Foo)
        {
            return this.Name == ((Foo)obj).Name;            
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The key to this is `Foo` must override `Equals()` to define what `Foo` objects can be considered duplicate, and the members that define which objects are duplicate should also be the `Dictionary<>` key (in this case `Name`)

If you can't override `Equals()` in `Foo`, then the other option is to use `Concat()` and `GroupBy()` instead of `Union()`

```
public Dictionary<String, Foo> Merge(XElement element1, XElement element2)
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> firstFoos = GetXmlData(element1); // parse 1st set from XML
    IEnumerable<Foo> secondFoos = GetXmlData(element2); // parse 2nd set from XML

    var result = firstFoos.Concat(secondFoos)
                          .GroupBy(foo => foo.Name)
                          .Select(grp => grp.First())
                          .ToDictionary(k=>k.Name, v=>v);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version creates a new entire dictionary instead of modifying one the dictionaries and merges the current dictionary with the supplied dictionary.

```html
/// <summary>
/// Merges the current dictionary with the supplied dictionary into a new dictionary.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
/// <param name="current"></param>
/// <param name="keyValuePairs"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Merge<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> current, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> keyValuePairs)
{
    var dictionaryMerge = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(current);
    foreach (var item in keyValuePairs)
    {
        dictionaryMerge[item.Key] = item.Value;
    }
    return dictionaryMerge;
}
```