# Add a LINQ or DBContext extension method to get an element if not exist then create with data in predicate (FirstOrCreate)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I'm trying to add a LINQ or DbContext extension method to get an element (FirstOrDefault) but if one does not already exist then create a new instance with data (FirstOrCreate) instead of returning null.

is this possible?

i.e.:

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static TSource FirstOrCreate<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source.First(predicate) != null)
        {
            return source.First(predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            return // ??? 
        }
    }
}
```

and a usage could be:

```
using (var db = new MsBoxContext())
{
    var status = db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrCreate(s => s.Name == "Enabled"); 
    //Here we should get the object if we find one
    //and if it doesn't exist create and return a new instance

    db.Entities.Add(new Entity()
    {
         Name = "New Entity",
         Status = status
    });
}
```

I hope that you understand my approach.

Comment: It would be easy to return a new one with no values set if it didn't find one, but do you want it to somehow look into the predicate and set properties on the new object based on what you were looking for? In this case, for instance, are you wanting it to return a status with Name == "Enabled"

Comment: thanks for quick response... right, that's exactly what I want...but i need to use this extension method to all entities (not only status) so should work in generic way...may be using reflection? also...how to read properties from predicate?

Comment: a quick solution to this issue is using ?? operator in that way: var status = db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Enabled") ?? new EntityStatus(){Name = "Enabled"}; but still want to know if is possible to get something with a generic extension method...

Comment: @NanoSassaroli possible. But I would recommend against it. You gain nothing by it.

Comment: @NanoSassaroli a predicate can contain pretty much anything; it won't necessarily just have properties. There may also be methods, other lambda expressions, etc., so there's not going to be a simple way to parse the predicate for the properties you're looking to set.

Comment: You're right that a pure predicate could be anything. Maybe what instead should happen is you pass in something like params Tuple<MemberExpression, object>>. At least you have more restrictions than a general predicate. And to do what you truly want to do, the extension method would need to be on DbSet<T>, not IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conclussion: 
instead of implement an extension method the best solution is using ?? operator in that way:

```
var status = db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Enabled") ?? new EntityStatus(){Name = "Enabled"};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static TSource FirstOrCreate<TSource>(
               this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
               Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate, 
               Func<T> defaultValue)
    {
        return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? defaultValue();
    }
}
```

usage

```
var status = db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrCreate(s => s.Name == "Enabled", 
                 () => new EntityStatus {Name = "Enabled"});
```

However you must note that this will not work quite like `FirstOrDefault()`.

If you did the following

```
var listOfStuff = new List<string>() { "Enabled" };
var statuses = from s in listOfStuff
               select db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrCreate(s => s.Name == "Enabled", 
                        () => new EntityStatus {Name = "Enabled"});
```

You would get O(n) hits to the database.

However I suspect if you did...

```
var listOfStuff = new List<string>() { "Enabled" };
var statuses = from s in listOfStuff
               select db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Enabled") 
                             ?? new EntityStatus {Name = "Enabled"};
```

It is plausible it could work...

Comment: Aron, thanks for your contribution, after that I can conlude that the easy/best efficient way to do that is using ?? operator instead of implementing/using an extension method.  ´var status = db.EntitiesStatus.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Enabled") ?? new EntityStatus(){Name = "Enabled"};´ agreed?

Answer (score 0):

I am a self taught programmer and I am really bad at typing so i was looking for the exact same thing. I ended up writing my own. It took a few steps and revisions before it would work with more than 1 property. Of course there are some limitations and I haven't fully tested it but so far it seems to work for my purposes of keeping the records distinct in the DB and shortening the code (typing time).

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static TEntity InsertIfNotExists<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> objectSet, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        TEntity entity;

        #region Check DB

        entity = objectSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (entity != null)
            return entity;

        #endregion

        //NOT in the Database... Check Local cotext so we do not enter duplicates
        #region Check Local Context

        entity = objectSet.Local().AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (entity != null)
            return entity;

        #endregion

        ///********* Does NOT exist create entity *********\\\
        entity = new TEntity();

        // Parse Expression Tree and set properties
        //Hit a recurrsive function to get all the properties and values
        var body = (BinaryExpression)((LambdaExpression)predicate).Body;
        var dict = body.GetDictionary();

        //Set Values on the new entity
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            entity.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(entity, item.Value);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, object> GetDictionary(this BinaryExpression exp)
    {
        //Recurssive function that creates a dictionary of the properties and values from the lambda expression
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
        {
            result.Merge(GetDictionary((BinaryExpression)exp.Left));
            result.Merge(GetDictionary((BinaryExpression)exp.Right));
        }
        else
        {
            result[((MemberExpression)exp.Left).Member.Name] = exp.Right.GetExpressionVaule();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static object GetExpressionVaule(this Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
            return ((ConstantExpression)exp).Value;

        if (exp.Type.IsValueType)
            exp = Expression.Convert(exp, typeof(object));

        //Taken From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238413/lambda-expression-tree-parsing
        var accessorExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(exp);
        Func<object> accessor = accessorExpression.Compile();
        return accessor();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Local<T>(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet) where T : class
    {
        //Taken From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2009/02/21/local-queries.aspx?Redirected=true
        return from stateEntry in objectSet.Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                   EntityState.Added | 
                   EntityState.Modified | 
                   EntityState.Unchanged)
               where stateEntry.Entity != null && stateEntry.EntitySet == objectSet.EntitySet
               select stateEntry.Entity as T;
    }

    public static void Merge<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> me, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> merge)
    {
        //Taken From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015204/c-sharp-merging-2-dictionaries

        foreach (var item in merge)
        {
            me[item.Key] = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is as simple as:

```
var status = db.EntitiesStatus.InsertIfNotExists(s => s.Name == "Enabled");
```

The extension will check the database first, if is not found it will check the local context (so you do not add it twice), if it is still not found it creates the entity, parses the expression tree to get the properties and values from the lambda expression, sets those values on a new entity, adds the entity to the context and returns the new entity.

A few things to be aware of...

1. This does not handle all possible uses (assumes all the expressions in the lambda are ==)
2. The project I did this in is using an ObjectContext as apposed to a DBContext (I have not switched yet so I don't know if this would work with DBContext. I assume it would not be difficult to change)
3. I am self-taught so there maybe many ways to optimize this. If you have any input please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What about this extension that also adds the new created entity to the DbSet.

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static TEntity FirstOrCreate<TEntity>(
            this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
            Func<TEntity> defaultValue)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var result = predicate != null
            ? dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate)
            : dbSet.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = defaultValue?.Invoke();
            if (result != null)
                dbSet.Add(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static TEntity FirstOrCreate<TEntity>(
            this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
            Func<TEntity> defaultValue)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return dbSet.FirstOrCreate(null, defaultValue);
    }

}
```

The usage with predicate:

```
var adminUser = DbContext.Users.FirstOrCreate(u => u.Name == "Admin", () => new User { Name = "Admin" });
```

or without predicate:

```
var adminUser = DbContext.Users.FirstOrCreate(() => new User { Name = "Admin" });
```